from distutils.version import LooseVersion
I am trying to deploy a streamlit app using Github, but I get this error: from distutils.version import LooseVersion.
The streamlit app runs fine when I use streamlit run main.py from Visuo Studio Code. But to deploy the app you need Github which is not allowing this seaborn version.
I tried downgrading Python to version 3.11, adding a runtime.txt on github with this version, but it did not help. I also tried updating seaborn to the latest version on my command prompt. But I'm not sure the command prompt helps when trying to deploy through GitHub?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
